# Setting up Django app on a shared hosting server

Tags: python, django, apache, shared-hosting

Okay so i have shared hosting so it means i have access to just about nothing so i'm having problems setting up my django application.

Looking at google searches there is a way to do it using a .htaccess and .wgsi file but I'm having no luck. My knowledge with anything like this is low as i normally use php.

So far i have added some code into the htaccess file and it always comes up with this error..

Not Found
The requested URL /dispatch.wsgi/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what toolset is available to you. I've used Webfaction on a shared server, and just click add application in the control panel, and choose a Django version, and bingo - it's all done

Comment: I recommend you stump up for 'real' hosting if you want to write 'real' web apps.

Comment: Where are you sharing your hosting from?

Comment: Did you tried [this tuto?](http://robhogg.me.uk/post/2) I tried and it works (with little touch ups). If you tried it and it didn't work, can you detail the error you got?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this :

In this **[section of django](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12.html#running-django-on-a-shared-hosting-provider-with-apache)** documentation they explain the how to :)

> Running Django on a Shared-Hosting Provider with Apache
>   Many shared-hosting providers don’t allow you to run your own server daemons or edit the httpd.conf file. In these cases, it’s still possible to run Django using Web server-spawned processes.

have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `dispatch.wsgi` on the specific path? it should be somewhere like the public folder that serves your static files, like `/public_html` or `/www`.

I have used shared hosting for django from a small orange. I got mine working by following [this tutorial](https://help.asmallorange.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/140) of theirs, maybe working for you too.